# How to save image in picture library in wp8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

How to save image from my app to picture library in WP8.1 runtime app? Any helpful links or code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this  first

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System.IO;
```

then declare

```
 BitmapImage bit = new BitmapImage();
    string filename;
CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask;
```

in the constructor

```
    cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
    cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCaptureTask_Completed);
```

Then copy paste this

```
  void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());
                bit.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                myImage.Source = bit;

                filename = "WP_" + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Ticks) + ".jpg";
                using (var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (isolatedStorage.FileExists(filename))
                        isolatedStorage.DeleteFile(filename);

                    IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isolatedStorage.CreateFile(filename);
                    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

                    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
                    wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                      fileStream.Close();
                }

                //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
                //System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                //bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                //myImage.Source = bmp;
            }
        }
```

then call this methhod where ever eyou want it

```
    cameraCaptureTask.Show();
```

To add to media library  do this copy the code given below

```
    var library = new MediaLibrary();

    using (var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isolatedStorage.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);


            var pic = library.SavePicture(filename, fileStream);

    }
```